# jQuery .lastLoad of several events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, load

I'm loading remote content into several divs and want to measure them and compare the results when all have loaded. What is the best way to get this event?

pseudo code:

```
$("#div1").load("www.foo.com/1");
$("#div2").load("www.foo.com/2");
$("#div3").load("www.foo.com/3");

function div1_and_div2_loaded(){
    alert("Success!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.when()` to execute code when a set of AJAX requests have completed. You will need to amend your code to use `$.ajax` though, as `load` does not return a deferred object. Try this:

```
var request1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.foo.com/1',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#div1').html(response);
    }
})

var request2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.foo.com/2',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#div2').html(response);
    }
})

$.when(request1, request2).done(function() {
    alert('success!');
});
```

The advantage of this pattern is that all* the requests will execute simultaneously, leading to a faster overall loading time.

*The browser may queue requests if you are making a lot of them.

Obviously you need to DRY up the creation of the requests, this is just a quick and dirty example.

Comment: could i pass a list to when? when([request1, request2]);

Comment: @SverkerSbrg unfortunately not. Annoyingly it only accepts individual arguments. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ You could extend it if required.

Comment: huh, is there anyway to do it dynamically? Without adding the requests to memory and checking eachone on load..